# Pandas write to csv without df.to_csv()

Tags: python, pandas

I want to generalize a write dataframe function where the dataframe and the write functions can be parameters.
e.g:

```
def save_dataframe(df, write_func, filename):
    write_func(df, filename)
```

and the usage would be like:

```
save_dataframe(df, pd.write_csv , "test.csv")
```

I know there are functions like `df.to_csv()` `df.to_excel()` etc. but I really want is a solution to generalize.

What I am looking is something like `pd.write_csv(df,filename)` similar to `pd.read_csv(filename)`

Thanks

Comment: Can you write your own? `def write_csv(df, filename): df.to_csv(filename)`

Comment: Not possible, because `save_dataframe` does not know the format the files are saved. `write_func` counld be `to_excel`, `to_json` or any custom function.

Comment: Why can't you pass `write_csv` as `write_func`? as long as the arguments conform you can pass anything. There is no difference to a function provided by pandas.

Comment: What @Plagon is saying is exactly what I was recommending.

Comment: @Plagon Pandas does not offer `pd.write_csv` function.

Comment: Use the function from @SethMMorton. You can pass any function as `write_func`.

Answer (score 0):

you can check for file extension to save in that class method

```
def write_func(df, filename):
  extensions_dict = {'csv':['csv'], 'excel':['xls', 'xlsx']}
  extension = filename.split(".")[-1]

  if extension in extensions_dict["csv"]:
     df.to_csv(df, filename)
  elif extension in extensions_dict["excel"]:
     df.to_excel(df, filename)
  # other extension checks ...
```